# Open source software for generic POE NVR hardware?

Tags: camera, video-surveillance

I have been looking for a piece of open-source software that can be loaded onto a generic Power over Ethernet (PoE) Network Video Recorder (NVR) device from a variety of different Chinese suppliers. I don't trust the software that is pre-loaded on them and would really like an alternative.

The NVR I am looking at has a Hi3536D processor/chipset and I would really like to be able to load something else onto it.

Comment: What should the software to be loaded do? You forgot to tell us that. Or, is it the loader software that you want?

Comment: I am looking for a piece of open-source software to replace the probably untrustworthy generic software that is pre-loaded on it so it can serve the same purpose, just more securely.

Comment: So, your looking for Network Video Recorder software, ***plus*** a way to load it?  The former might be difficult, the latter might range form tricky to impossible. An admirable project, though. Good luck :-)